# Can't install Modelling SDK in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. 
While trying to install Modelling SDK, I get a message

> Setup blocked. Microsoft Visual Studio SDK is required, but it is not installed
>   on this computer. Please install it and retry.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried to install Microsoft Visual Studio SDK?

Comment: Well, I installed Visual Studio. I thought that the SDK was in it. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure you update your install to include the following**

[read more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt683786.aspx)

[image]